# Sort an array of objects by two fields one with the end time first and if the end time is same then sort with status based on order of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, sorting

Is this the correct approach to sort data by using infinity..? tried the solution but it's not quite what I need.

```js
data = [{
  "status": "Accepted",
  "endTime": ""
}, {
  "status": "New",
  "endTime": "Sep 16 2022, 04:18 GMT+5"
}, {
  "status": "In Progress",
  "endTime": "Sep 16 2022, 04:18 GMT+5"
}, {
  "status": "Accepted",
  "endTime": "Sep 16 2022, 04:19 GMT+5"
}, {
  "status": "Kick Off Policy Review Task",
  "endTime": "Sep 16 2022, 04:13 GMT+5"
}];

// sort based on this order
sortDSCOrder = [
  'Canceled',
  'Accepted',
  'Completed',
  'On-Hold',
  'In Progress',
  'Not Started',
  'New',
  'Kick Off General Query Task',
  'Kick Off Policy Review Task',
];
```

Desc sort:

```js
data.sort((a, b) => {
  return (
    (b.endTime ? new Date(b.endTime).getTime() : Infinity) -
    (a.endTime ? new Date(a.endTime).getTime() : Infinity) ||
    this.sortDSCOrder.indexOf(a.status) -
    this.sortDSCOrder.indexOf(b.status)
  );
});

ouptput = [{
  "status": "Accepted",
  "endTime": ""
}, {
  "status": "Accepted",
  "endTime": "Sep 16 2022, 04:19 GMT+5"
}, {
  "status": "In Progress",
  "endTime": "Sep 16 2022, 04:18 GMT+5"
}, {
  "status": "New",
  "endTime": "Sep 16 2022, 04:18 GMT+5"
}, {
  "status": "Kick Off Policy Review Task",
  "endTime": "Sep 16 2022, 04:13 GMT+5"
}];
```

Comment: `tried the solution but it's not quite what I need` then what is what you need? We can't debug code if you don't tell us what your requirement is.

Comment: without using infinity..is there any approach to do it in a different way..? when the end time is null or empty that has to be on top

Comment: is the above result the wanted one? what goes wrong with the code?

Comment: yes, that is the exact output. But, when the end time is null or empty the record has to be on top.
Is this the better approach to sort the data by using INFINITY..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because the logic you're using to convert the values to a date is flawed. The dates will move to the top when null due to type coercion when converted to Date objects, and when you return `1` or `-1` after the comparison instead of subtracting their values. Comparing in this manner means that you don't need to coerce null/empty values to `Infinity` for them to appear first.

```js
const sortDSCOrder = ["Canceled","Accepted","Completed","On-Hold","In Progress","Not Started","New","Kick Off General Query Task","Kick Off Policy Review Task",];
const data = [{status:"Accepted",endTime:""},{status:"New",endTime:"Sep 16 2022, 04:18 GMT+5"},{status:"In Progress",endTime:"Sep 16 2022, 04:18 GMT+5"},{status:"Accepted",endTime:"Sep 16 2022, 04:19 GMT+5"},{status:"Kick Off Policy Review Task",endTime:"Sep 16 2022, 04:13 GMT+5"}];

data.sort((a, b) => {
  const aDate = new Date(a.endTime);
  const bDate = new Date(b.endTime);
  const aStateIndex = sortDSCOrder.indexOf(a.status);
  const bStateIndex = sortDSCOrder.indexOf(b.status);
  return aDate < bDate ? 1 : aDate > bDate ? -1 : aStateIndex - bStateIndex;
});

console.log(data);
```